# Apache Flink: How to apply custom logic to late events?

Tags: streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Even though Flink has some built-in tooling to handle late data, like *allowed lateness*, I'd like to handle the late data by myself. For example, I'd like to monitor late event or just save them to a database.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProcessFunctions (`ProcessFunction`, `KeyedProcessFunction`, etc.) provide access to the event timestamp of a record and the `TimerService` via a `Context` object. The `TimerService` gives access to the current watermark.

You can identify late records by comparing the event timestamp and the watermark. If the timestamp is less or equal to the watermark, the event is late.

It is up to you how you want to handle late events. You can mark them, you can discard them, emit them via a side output, or perform any kind of computation with them.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! I tried to get watermark by "ctx.timerService().currentWatermark()" but it always return -9223372036854775808, Did I miss anything?

Comment: Do you have event-time processing enabled and do you assign watermarks?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the lateness and watermarks are used in window operators. And If you're using window operator, you can use the sideoutput like this:

```
val windowStream = eventStream.keyBy(output => output.rule)
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)))
  .sideOutputLateData(lateOutputTag)
```

And get the late elements from the sideoutput like this:

```
windowStream.getSideOutput(lateOutputTag).print()
```